# MONGO NO APARECE

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, mongod

Estoy intentando ejecutar mongo en la terminal pero dice que el comando no es reconocido, he visto muchos tutoriales de ayuda pero ninguno funciona y me he dado cuenta que al descargar el mongodb el mongo.exe no viene en el paquete, solo viene mongod.exe y mongos.exe pero solo se ejecuta el mongod.exe.

cabe aclaar que ya he hecho todo y aun no funciona, he agregado las variables de entorno y aun no me sirve, porfavor ayudaa.!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Dependienddo de la versión de MongoDB que hayas instalado, la ruta de los ejecutables en Windows suele ser como la siguiente: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin`. Allí encontrarás el ejecutable que buscas. Añada dicha ruta a la variable PATH del sistema. La ruta aquí mostrada corresponde a MongoDB 5.x sobre Windows 10. Saludos